# How to use two arrays in a shell script for loop?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have two arrays in a bash script, every array have same number of elements, I need to write 2nd array's every element for every element in the first array in a for loop

first array name: ARR_MPOINT

second array name: ARR_LVNAME

piece of the script:

```
ARR_MPOINT=(/tmp /var /log);
ARR_LVNAME=(lv_tmp lv_var lv_log)

for MPOINT in "${ARR_MPOINT[@]}"
    do
        echo "/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-${ARR_LVNAME[@]}     $MPOINT         xfs      defaults        1 2" 
    done

I need to print below output

/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-lv_tmp      /tmp        xfs      defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-lv_var      /var        xfs      defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-lv_log      /log        xfs      defaults        1 2
```

Comment: A nested for loop that iterates over `ARR_LVNAME` should do the trick. Just realized you want 3 iterations instead of 9 but access both arrays at the same index.

Comment: Use a for loop like `for i in {0..$ARRAY_SIZE}`. Then something like `echo "/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-${ARR_LVNAME[i]}     ${ARR_MPOINT[i]} ..."`

Comment: How can I edit ${ARR_LVNAME[@]} ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403498/iterate-over-two-arrays-simultaneously-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays have the same length you can access the elements by index:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#ARR_MPOINT[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-${ARR_LVNAME[i]}     ${ARR_MPOINT[i]}         xfs      defaults        1 2" 
done
```

Comment: thanks this will work. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `/` with `lv_` and only use the first array to get the output:

```
for MPOINT in "${ARR_MPOINT[@]}"; do
    echo "/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-${MPOINT//\//lv_} $MPOINT xfs defaults 1 2" 
done
```