# Bash Arrays - Zip array of variable names with corresponding values

Tags: arrays, bash, pointers, eval, indirection

As I am teaching myself Bash programming, I came across an interesting use case, where **I want to take a list of variables that exist in the environment, and put them into an array.  Then, I want to output a list of the variable names and their values, and store that output in an array, one entry per variable.**

I'm only about 2 weeks into Bash shell scripting in any "real" way, and I am educating myself on arrays.  A common function in other programming language is the ability to "zip" two arrays, e.g. [as is done in Python](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/).  Another common feature in any programming language is indirection, e.g. via [pointer indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)), etc.  This is largely academic, to teach myself through a somewhat challenging example, but I think this has widespread use if for no other reason than debugging, keeping track of overall system state, etc.

**What I want is for the following input... :**

```
VAR_ONE="LIGHT RED"
VAR_TWO="DARK GREEN"
VAR_THREE="BLUE"
VARIABLE_ARRAY=(VAR_ONE VAR_TWO VAR_THREE)
```

**... to be converted into the following output (as an array, one element per line):**

```
VAR_ONE: LIGHT RED
VAR_TWO: DARK GREEN
VAR_THREE: BLUE
```

**Constraints:**

- Assume that I do not have control of all of the variables, so I cannot just sidestep the problem e.g. by using an associative array from the get-go.  (i.e. please do not recommend avoiding the need for indirect reference lookups altogether by never having a discrete variable named "VAR_ONE").  But a solution that stores the result in an associative array is fine.
- Assume that variable names will never contain spaces, but their values might.
- The final output should *not* contain separate elements just because the input variables had values containing spaces.

**What I've read about so far:**

- I've read some StackOverflow posts like this one, that deal with using indirect references to arrays *themselves* (e.g. if you have three arrays and want to choose which one to pull from based on an "array choice" variable): [How to iterate over an array using indirect reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11180714/12854372)
- I've also found one single post that deals with "zipping" arrays in Bash in the manner I'm talking about, where you pair-up e.g. the 1st element from `array1` and `array2`, then pair up the 2nd elements, etc.: [Iterate over two arrays simultaneously in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403498/iterate-over-two-arrays-simultaneously-in-bash)
- ...but I haven't found anything that quite discusses this unique use-case...

**QUESTION:**

**How should I make an array containing a list of variable names and their values (colon-separated), given an array containing a list of variable names only. I'm not "failing to come up with any way to do it" but I want to find the "preferred" way to do this in Bash, considering performance, security, and being concise/understandable.**

EDIT: I'll post what I've come up with thus far as an answer to this post... but not mark it as answered, since I want to also hear some unbiased recommendations...

Comment: if you don't mind using the variable names as the array index, consider using an associative array (`declare -A arrayname`); as for the rest of your question(s) ... I'd suggest you focus on a single issue that you're having and then either a) update the question, focusing on that one issue or b) close/delete this question and open a new more-focused question; this question will likely get flagged for closure because a) there's no focus on one particular issue and b) you appear to be asking for opinions

Comment: I don't understand why you exclude associative arrays because you do not "have control of all of the variables" – that shouldn't matter? And I agree with @markp-fuso, this seems to be many questions at once.

Comment: I'll admit I stopped reading the question half way thru (no focus, rambling) so missed OP's comment about associative arrays; the missive (?) about using associative arrays due to spaces in the values doesn't make sense ... the associative array index and values may contain white space ... ?  not sure how OP plans to 'zip' a list of variables if all the names are not known ... ??

Comment: @markp-fuso : Edited the question to put my own ideas as an answer instead of in the main post.  Regarding a single issue, it is: make an array containing a list of variable names and their values (colon-separated), given an array containing a list of variable names only.  I'll admit that I'm not "failing to come up with any way to do it" but I want to find the "preferred" way to do this in Bash, considering performance, security, and being concise/understandable.  I'll note this in the original post.

Comment: @BenjaminW. If you have an idea using associative arrays, please do share.  What I meant is that I've read some posts saying to "avoid setting yourself up for the need to use indirect references altogether" by storing name/value pairs (e.g. [VAR_1] = LIGHT RED) in an associative array "from the start".  Assume that I'm using predefined system environment variables.  But if you have a way to collect the values from those variables and put them *into* an associative array, that would be a good solution.  Would that make the final "printout" step a little more verbose, though?

Answer (score 1):

OP starts with:

```
VAR_ONE="LIGHT RED"
VAR_TWO="DARK GREEN"
VAR_THREE="BLUE"
VARIABLE_ARRAY=(VAR_ONE VAR_TWO VAR_THREE)
```

OP has provided an answer with 4 sets of code:

```
# first 3 sets of code generate:

$ typeset -p outputValues
declare -a outputValues=([0]="VAR_ONE: LIGHT RED" [1]="VAR_TWO: DARK GREEN" [2]="VAR_THREE: BLUE")

# the 4th set of code generates the following where the data values are truncated at the first space:

$ typeset -p outputValues
declare -a outputValues=([0]="VAR_ONE: LIGHT" [1]="VAR_TWO: DARK" [2]="VAR_THREE: BLUE")
```

**NOTES**:

- I'm assuming the output from the 4th set of code is wrong so will be ignoring this one
- OP's code samples touch on a couple ideas I'm going to make use of (below) ... nameref's (`declare -n <variable_name>`) and indirect variable references (`${!<variable_name>}`)

---

---

For readability (and maintainability by others) I'd probably avoid the various `eval` and expansion ideas and instead opt for using `bash` namesref's (`declare -n`); a quick example:

```
$ x=5
$ echo "${x}"
5

$ y=x
$ echo "${y}"
x

$ declare -n y="x"          # nameref => y=(value of x)
$ echo "${y}"
5
```

Pulling this into the original issue we get:

```
unset outputValues
declare -a outputValues                           # optional; declare 'normal' array

for var_name in "${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    declare -n data_value="${var_name}"
    outputValues+=("${var_name}: ${data_value}")
done
```

Which gives us:

```
$ typeset -p outputValues
declare -a outputValues=([0]="VAR_ONE: LIGHT RED" [1]="VAR_TWO: DARK GREEN" [2]="VAR_THREE: BLUE")
```

While this generates the same results (as OP's first 3 sets of code) there is (for me) the nagging question of how is this new array going to be used?

If the sole objective is to print this pre-formatted data to stdout ... ok, though why bother with a new array when the same can be done with the current array and nameref's?

If the objective is to access this array as sets of variable name/value pairs for processing purposes, then the current structure is going to be hard(er) to work with, eg, each array 'value' will need to be parsed/split based on the delimiter `:<space>` in order to access the actual variable names and values.

In this scenario I'd opt for using an associative array, eg:

```
unset outputValues
declare -A outputValues                           # required; declare associative array

for var_name in "${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    declare -n data_value="${var_name}"
    outputValues[${var_name}]="${data_value}"
done
```

Which gives us:

```
$ typeset -p outputValues
declare -A outputValues=([VAR_ONE]="LIGHT RED" [VAR_THREE]="BLUE" [VAR_TWO]="DARK GREEN" )
```

**NOTES**:

- again, why bother with a new array when the same can be done with the current array and nameref's?
- if the variable `$data_value` is to be re-used in follow-on code as a 'normal' variable it will be necessary to remove the nameref attribute (`unset -n data_value`)

With an associative array (index=variable name / array element=variable value) it becomes easier to reference the variable name/value pairs, eg:

```
$ myvar=VAR_ONE
$ echo "${myvar}: ${outputValues[${myvar}]}"
VAR_ONE: LIGHT RED

$ for var_name in "${!outputValues[@]}"; do echo "${var_name}: ${outputValues[${var_name}]}"; done
VAR_ONE: LIGHT RED
VAR_THREE: BLUE
VAR_TWO: DARK GREEN
```

---

---

In older versions of `bash` (before nameref's were available), and still available in newer versions of `bash`, there's the option of using indirect variable references;

```
$ x=5
$ echo "${x}"
5

$ unset -n y        # make sure 'y' has not been previously defined as a nameref
$ y=x
$ echo "${y}"
x

$ echo "${!y}"
5
```

Pulling this into the associative array approach:

```
unset -n var_name                                 # make sure var_name not previously defined as a nameref
unset outputValues
declare -A outputValues                           # required; declare associative array

for var_name in "${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    outputValues[${var_name}]="${!var_name}"
done
```

Which gives us:

```
$ typeset -p outputValues
declare -A outputValues=([VAR_ONE]="LIGHT RED" [VAR_THREE]="BLUE" [VAR_TWO]="DARK GREEN" )
```

**NOTE**: While this requires less coding in the `for` loop, if you forget to `unset -n` the variable (`var_name` in this case) then you'll end up with the wrong results if `var_name` was previously defined as a nameref; perhaps a minor issue but it requires the coder to know of, and code for, this particular issue ... a bit too esoteric (for my taste) so I prefer to stick with namerefs ... ymmv ...

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso, I particularly like using the original array when you're printing-out values in your associative array.  Otherwise, the ideas I was coming up with made that part kind of verbose.  I don't fully follow "again, why bother with a new array when the same can be done with the current array and nameref's?"  My idea for that was then I can do whatever I want with the output - print it, format it, use it for later assignments, etc.  Although I agree that the colon symbols in my version makes that harder than your associative array method!

Comment: And yes, in the 4th set of code, I guess I had set `IFS=""` earlier on my machine.  Running it from a fresh shell, I agree with your findings, it is not fully-correct as I listed the code in this post.  I'll update it in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a handful of possible solutions in the last couple days, each one with their own pro's and con's.  I won't mark this as the answer for awhile though, since I'm interested in hearing unbiased recommendations.

---

My brainstorming solutions thus far:

OPTION #1 - FOR-LOOP:

```
alias PrintCommandValues='unset outputValues
for var in ${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]}
do outputValues+=("${var}: ${!var}")
done; printf "%s\n\n" "${outputValues[@]}"'
PrintCommandValues
```

Pro's: Traditional, easy to understand

Cons: A little verbose.  I'm not sure about Bash, but I've been doing a lot of Mathematica programming (imperative-style), where such loops are notably slower.  Anybody know if that's true for Bash?

OPTION #2 - EVAL:

```
i=0; outputValues=("${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]}")
eval declare "${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]/#/outputValues[i++]+=:\\ $}"
printf "%s\n\n" "${outputValues[@]}"
```

Pros: Shorter than the for-loop, and still easy to understand.

Cons: I'm no expert, but I've read a lot of warnings to avoid `eval` whenever possible, due to security issues.  Probably not something I'll concern myself a ton over when I'm mostly writing scripts for "handy utility purposes" for my personal machine only, but...

OPTION #3 - QUOTED DECLARE WITH PARENTHESIS:

```
i=0; declare -a outputValues="(${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]/%/'\:\ "${!VARIABLE_ARRAY[i++]}"'})"
printf "%s\n\n" "${outputValues[@]}"
```

Pros: Super-concise.  I just plain stumbled onto this syntax -- I haven't found it mentioned anywhere on the web.  Apparently, using `declare` in Bash (I use version 4.4.20(1)), if (**and ONLY if**) you place array-style `(...)` brackets after the equals-sign, and quote it, you get one more "round" of expansion/dereferencing, similar to `eval`.  I happened to be toying with [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1186997), and found the part about the "extra expansion" by accident.

For example, compare these two tests:

```
varName=varOne; varOne=something
declare test1=\$$varName
declare -a test2="(\$$varName)"
declare -p test1 test2
```

Output:

```
declare -- test1="\$varOne"
declare -a test2=([0]="something")
```

Pretty neat, I think...

Anyways, the cons for this method are... I've never seen it documented officially or unofficially anywhere, so... portability...?

Alternative for this option:

```
i=0; declare -a LABELED_VARIABLE_ARRAY="(${VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]/%/'\:\ \$"${VARIABLE_ARRAY[i++]}"'})"
declare -a outputValues=("${LABELED_VARIABLE_ARRAY[@]@P}")
printf "%s\n\n" "${outputValues[@]}"
```

JUST FOR FUN - BRACE EXPANSION:

```
unset outputValues; OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=; i=0; j=0
declare -n nameCursor=outputValues[i++]; declare -n valueCursor=outputValues[j++]
declare {nameCursor+=,valueCursor+=": "$}{VAR_ONE,VAR_TWO,VAR_THREE}
printf "%s\n\n" "${outputValues[@]}"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Pros: ??? Maybe speed?

Cons: Pretty verbose, not very easy to understand

---

Anyways, those are all of my methods... Are any of them reasonable, or would you do something different altogether?