# bash, merge two comma separated variables values to single variable

Tags: string, bash

I have two commas separate variables like below. on a certain condition, I need to merge two variables into a single. Bit confused and unsure if is it possible in bash

**Input**

```
SBI=abc,def,ijk
MEM=one,two,three
```

**Expected output**

```
OUT=abc_one,def_two,ijk_three
```

Comment: please add your attempted code

Comment: Note that all-caps names are used for variables that have special meaning for the shell or operating system; names you define yourself should have at least one lower-case character. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- the convention applies to regular variables as well as environment variables because they share a namespace (setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple extension of [Iterate over two arrays simultaneously in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403498/iterate-over-two-arrays-simultaneously-in-bash), combined with [How to split a string into an array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash).

```
IFS=, read -ra sbi_arr <<<"$SBI" # convert SBI string to an array
IFS=, read -ra mem_arr <<<"$MEM" # convert MEM string to an array

out=                             # initialize output variable
for idx in "${!sbi_arr[@]}"; do  # iterate by indices
  out+="${sbi_arr[$idx]}_${mem_arr[$idx]}," # append to output
done
out=${out%,}                     # strip trailing comma from output

echo "Output is: $out"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` command substitution, process substitution, parameter expansion and, `paste` utility:

```
OUT=$(paste -d_ <(echo "${SBI//,/$'\n'}") <(echo "${MEM//,/$'\n'}"))
OUT=${OUT//$'\n'/,}
echo "OUT=$OUT"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh

SBI=abc,def,ijk
MEM=one,two,three

out=$(
  while [ -n "$SBI" ] && [ -n "$MEM" ]; do
    sbi_first="${SBI%%,*}"
    sbi_rest="${SBI#*"$sbi_first"}"
    mem_first="${MEM%%,*}"
    mem_rest="${MEM#*"$mem_first"}"
    SBI="${sbi_rest#,}"
    MEM="${mem_rest#,}"
    printf '%s_%s,' "$sbi_first" "$mem_first"
  done
)

echo "${out%,}"
```

---

With `bash`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SBI=abc,def,ijk
MEM=one,two,three

while IFS= read -ru3 str0; do
  IFS= read -r str1
  out+="${str0}_$str1,"
done 3<<< "${SBI//,/$'\n'}" <<<"${MEM//,/$'\n'}"

echo "${out%,}"
```